# The updated material design (mdc - 2018) vs. angular (dart) components

Tags: angular-material, angular-dart, mdc-components

I'm new to Angular and I'm a bit confused whether the implementation of the angular components reflects the recent (2018) material design system changes or they are just updating the old version of the system?

the Angular components version is been updated:
https://trimox.github.io/angular-mdc-web/#/angular-mdc-web/home

But it seems to me that the Angular Dart components version is still using the old system:
https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/

Am I missing something or the Angular components will not get the latest material design updates?
(I think the Angular team is using foundations and adapters to adapt the vanilla web version of the updated material design system, is the Angular Dart team doing the same?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specs and M2 components are still being worked on. We have some ready, but I don't see us releasing them until after internal teams have shaken out most of the bugs. They are still going through big API changes to make sure they work well in our products.

There is one that is released which is the material_card.